# Google Fonts looks different at google.com and at my web site

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-size

I just tried to use Google Fonts and have noticed the following disturbing effect:
 The result of using the font at my custom html file is different from what's present on Google site.
 At least the font size is definitely different (color is also different, but it doesn't matter).

Font: Slabo 27px, size: 112px
Link to the Google Fonts: https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Slabo+27px
The browser is the same: Firefox.

At google:
[image: At google.com/fonts]
At my site
[image: On my site]

HTLM code that I used:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Slabo+27px"> 

<div class="end">
  <p>Regular</p>
</div>
```

main.css:

```
.end {
    font-family: 'Slabo 27px';
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 112px;
    color: #212121;
}
```

Any ideas what cause such effect??

Update:
Arrgh, it was just me being inattentive.
Google page turned out to be zoomed the whole time.
I compared them after zoom reset and confirmed that they are identical.

Comment: Can you show us the exact line you have for including the font in your site. Are you using a <link> tag in HTML or an @import in CSS? Plus did you ensure that both browser windows are at the same zoom level?

Comment: It looks to my (non-designer) eyes like the difference is in the font size. I can't see a shape difference letter-to-letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

same, don't see difference, both have size 112px. https://jsfiddle.net/fp9j7L85/

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Slabo+27px" rel="stylesheet">
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I honestly don't see a difference. Apart from the color and size.

Yours looks a bit sharper. But I wouldn't complain about that.